# Input calculates to invalid time: 24:00:00 in big query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, legacy-sql

I am running a query to bring time in 24 hr format but when i run query and it calculates time over 23:59:59, instead of going over and changing time to 00:00:00 it gives me error saying Input calculates to invalid time: 24:00:00.

```
 FORMAT_TIME('%T',
TIME(DIV(sc.timestart, 60),
  MOD(sc.timestart, 60),
  0)) AS TimeFrom,

FORMAT_TIME('%k',
TIME(DIV(sc.timestart + sc.timeduration, 60),
  MOD(sc.timestart + sc.timeduration, 60),
0)) AS TimeTo
```

Error Input calculates to invalid time: 24:00:00

```
 Row ClassID    TimeFrom    timeduration     Timeto_shouldBE
 1  7786918     23:00:00        60   
 2  339893      23:00:00        30   
 3  4665919     23:00:00        60   
 4  7384955     23:00:00        60   
 5  6863540     23:30:00        30   
 6  2891444     23:30:00        30
```

trying to calculate it from 23:00:00 to 00:00:00 or beyond

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ClassID, 
  TIME(TIMESTAMP_ADD(TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE()), INTERVAL timestart MINUTE)) AS TimeFrom,
  timeduration,
  TIME(TIMESTAMP_ADD(TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE()), INTERVAL timestart + timeduration MINUTE)) AS TimeTo
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Answer (score 1):

This works fine with the `time` data type:

```
select time_add(cast('23:00:00' as time), interval 120 minute)
```

I would suggest that you use this structure for your expression.